# Ruby: how to ignore words in 'when'

Tags: ruby, telegram

How do I make the bot reply even if user’s message doesn’t 100% match with words I wrote in ‘when’? I want to make the bot trigger if someone sent “hello there”, for example, instead of just hello.

I’ve heard about `when include?('example')` but I can’t make it work.

```
    require 'telegram/bot'

token = 'x'

Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot|

bot.listen do |message|
   puts "@#{message.from.username}: #{message.text}"
  case message.text

when 'hello'
    bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "answer")

end
end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) to match your text:

```
case message.text
when /hello/   # matches if there is the 'hello' somewhere in the string
  # ...
when /\Ahello/ # matches if the string starts with 'hello'
  # ...
end
```

Or you can use `include?` in an `if` condition:

```
if message.text.include?('hello')
  # ...
end
```

Comment: It was so simple, and I've struggled with this for so long. Thank you so much!

Comment: (noob in the house)

Comment: Also, you could use `/hello/i` for case insensitive matching. (Or alternatively, do that `case`/`if` statement on `message.text.downcase`.)